# Manifest File Not Found while Building New Azure Fabric Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, msbuild, manifest, azure-service-fabric

We have a Microsoft Azure Service Fabric application that was created using Visual Studio 2015.  The solution already contains a number of projects and services--some acting as backend code and others as Web API services that provide web methods.  I am trying to add a new Web API service (called `ReportingSvcWebApi`, implemented in a project called `ReportingService.WebApi`).  I added the proper references to the service in the fabric's `ApplicationManifest.xml` file.  I've verified that if I build and debug locally, I can ping the `ReportingSvcWebApi` service, using Postman to create a web request that calls one of the methods in the controller I created and gets the proper response.  Thus, the service seems to be properly integrated into our fabric.

However, when I check in my changes and launch a build in Team Explorer, I get an error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (4875): Could not copy the file "E:\[PATH-TO-OUR-SOLUTION-ON-THE-BULID-SERVER]\Binaries\ReportingService.WebApi\ReportingSvc.WebApi.exe.manifest" because it was not found.`

Note that `ReportingSvc.WebApi.exe` is the name of the output assembly for the `ReportingService.WebApi` project that I set in the project's properties. It's also the value set in the `CodePackage/EntryPoint/ExeHost/Program` tag of the Reporting service's `ServiceManifest.xml` file.  Also, in the build logs, before the error occurs, I can see a number of targets run and succeed on all projects in the solution, including the Reporting service ("default targets", `GetNativeManifest`, and`GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems`).  The failure appears to occur during the execution of the `Publish` target for the Reporting service.

I've seen other people report the missing .exe.manifest file error, but never for a Service Fabric service.  Also, I'd managed to add another service (an ASP.NET Core MVC service) to our Service Fabric solution previously without having this problem.  Finally, I can't find any mention of manifests in any of our projects, aside from the ApplicationManifest.xml and ServiceManifest.xml files that I don't believe are related to the error.  Is there an option I need to set somewhere to either generate a .exe.manifest file for my project, or prevent MSBuild from looking for it?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by opening up the service's .csproj file in a text editor and adding the following alongside the other `<PropertyGroup>` elements:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

The other, preexisting projects in the solution didn't have this element and still built fine.  I'm not sure why this was necessary in this case.